# Reading and writing to the same file using try-with-resources

Tags: java, file-io, variadic-functions, try-with-resources

I am trying to make a program that receives a specified `String`, and removes every occurence of this `String` in a text document. The text file that is used to read / write is the same. The arguments used are received from cmd, in this order:

```
inputString filename
```

The program compiles fine, but after running it leaves the original text file blank. If i make a try-catch block for input handling, and a try-catch block for output handling, I am able to read and write to the same file. If i use a try-with-resources block, I am able to read a file, and save the output to a different file than the original, with all occurences of `inputString` from cmd removed. But it seems like I can't read and write to the same file using try-with-resources, and also the `input.hasNext()` statement returns false when I try to do it this way.

Code example below:

```
package ch12;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Chapter_12_E11_RemoveText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage java ch12.Chapter_12_E11_RemoveText inputString filename");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        File filename = new File(args[1]);
        if (!filename.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Target file " + args[1] + " does not exist");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        try (
            Scanner input = new Scanner(filename);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(filename); 
        ) {

            System.out.println("hasNext() is " + input.hasNext());
            System.out.println("hasNextLine() is " + input.hasNextLine());

            while (input.hasNext()) {

                String s1 = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("String fetched from input.nextLine() " + s1);
                System.out.println("Attemping to replace all words equal to " + args[0] + " with \"\"");
                String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[0], "");
                output.println(s2);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am suspecting that when I create a new `PrintWriter` object with the argument `filename`, the original file is overwritten by a blank file before the `while-loop` executes. Am i right here? Is it possible to read and write to the same file using try-with-resources?

Comment: Closed as duplicate with wrong duplicate. Re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PrintWriter [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29):

> If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.

So you are correct, by the time you initialize your `PrintWriter`, your `Scanner` has nothing to scan.

I would remove the `PrintWriter` initialization from the resources initialization block, build your file representation in memory, then replace the file contents in another block (or nest it).

That is, if the file has a reasonable size for your memory to handle the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I probably should have figured this one out alone ;)

Comment: @Esben86 you're welcome. You kind of *did* figure it out actually :)